# AngularJS 1.2 + ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to migrate from Angular1.0.6 + ui-router to Angular1.2.
But unfortunately my ui-router implementation seems to be not working with angular1.2
To be noted, everything (ui-router) is working nicely with Angular1.0.6 and even it is working ok with Angular1.1.4

Is anyone out there facing this issue? Or should I do anything extra to make Angular1.2 + ui-router working?

This is the error I am getting

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
     at $LocationProvider.<anonymous> (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:8806:18)
     at Object.invoke (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3617:28)
     at file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3450:37
     at getService (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3571:39)
     at Object.invoke (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3593:13)
     at file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3450:37
     at getService (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3571:39)
     at Object.invoke (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:3593:13)
     at file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5106:43
     at Array.forEach (native) at file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:9037
 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'
     at file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:14434:15
     at nodeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:6088:13)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5521:15)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5524:13)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5524:13)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5524:13)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5524:13)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5524:13)
     at compositeLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5524:13)
     at publicLinkFn (file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:5421:30) at file:///data/data/test/files/content/www/lib/angular.min.js:9037
```

Comment: do you get any particular error messages?

Comment: Do you have jQuery on that page? If you do, which version?

Comment: @Heikki, Yes I have jquery in my page and it is 1.9.0

Comment: Hmm.. weird. I thought I got it. Could you run `jQuery.fn.jquery` in Chrome console and see what it outputs?

Comment: @Heikki, I ran this $().jquery and $.fn.jquery both gave me same result 1.9.0

Comment: @Heilli Thanks for your help.
Now I could successfully migrated to AngualrJS1.2. But I have to say, the original issue was with the JQuery version that I was using. I got rid of JQuey and it is working fine now.
Thanks again.